# sftp connection not established

Tags: ssh, unix, sftp, ssh-keys

I am receiving the following error message when I try to connect to the remote host via sftp

> Disconnected; connection lost(connection closed)
>
> Warning: child process (/usr/bin/ssh2) exited with code 74.

The keys are properly installed.
Does anyone know what's causing the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It is due to Connection failed error.

Refer below link,

http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2116.html

If you want to connect from server1 (user1) to server2 (user2), you have to create the keys for user1 in server1 (ssh-keygen -t rsa/dsa), then get the public key and copy it to /home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys
Set the appropiate perms for the files and check that both machies are resolving their IP/names.
By default, usually, sshd have cert auth activated so you should not have any problem.

As you can check following,

(i) get the public key and copy it to /home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys was already done

(ii) Set the appropiate perms for the files - what should the perms be, please (700) ??

(iii) and check that both machies are resolving their IP/names.